# Loading large amount of Records from XML to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, xml, html, records

I am reading records from a XML file and displaying it in a dynamically created HTML table(inside a div whose id ="content") with javascript using push method. When the number of records is below 1000 the script executes normally and the contents are displayed. But when the number of records exceeds 1 million the browser(Currently using Firefox) warns me as Unresponsive script(A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete). I know that we can split the records and display with page navigation, but I need to display all the records in the current view just as in Yahoo!Mail's In Scrolling Option. Or before all the records are displayed I want to show a Loading image in the "content" div and after that have to display the HTML table with the xml contents. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reason for that. Loading millions of records into a web page is not a good idea as it will consume your pc memory. as simple as that
People do alot of workaround for that, you can use paging to go back and forth. you can also use lazy loading. like you can see only 10 records at a time, so records are loaded dynamically while scrolling down a page
Many js libraries have different implementation for paging and lazy loading. 
Here's a paging example from Extjs
[enter link description here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/paging.html)

Paging and lazy loading. Use one of these techniques

Answer (score 0):

you can load some records initially after when scroll reach at end load more records and so on.You can use following javascript code to check scroll end and so load more records:

```
$('#id').bind('scroll', function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
                //load more records
            }
        });
```